# flash message doesn't show up

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-4

My code for form validation requires flash messages, however, it doesn't show up in my Chrome (version: 85.0.4183.102 - 64bit):

My other environment info is listed below:

Python 3.8.5
Flask 1.1.2
Werkzeug 1.0.1
Bootstrap 4.5.2

Here is the webpage.py code block:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data}!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)


@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.email.data == 'test@test.com' and form.password.data == 'test':
            flash('You have been logged in!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unseccessful. Please check username and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

And here is the layout.html code block:

```
{% with message = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for category, message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
                {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: What's the HTML before and after this? This needs to be in the <body> of the page for it to be visiable...

Comment: Yes, it is inside the <body> tag.

Comment: Share more of the HTML of the template?

Comment: check my answer, any questions feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

try it and let me know.

This is yours:

```
{% with message = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for category, message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
                {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

### Instead use this

---

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for category, message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
                {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

if not working try a simpler version like this (this should work 100%) if this work that the issue is somewhere in how you implement get_flashed_messages in the HTML:

```
{% for msg in get_flashed_messages() %}

    <div class="alert alert-dangerous">
         {{ msg }}
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

### UPDATED

I also found a small bug in login():

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.email.data == 'test@test.com' and form.password.data == 'test':
            flash('You have been logged in!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unseccessful. Please check username and password', 'danger')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

**Added `return redirect(url_for('home'))` after the else statement**
Otherwise that flash will never show up